# Don't get response when I use @query in rettofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using Rettofite 2 for handling http services but I don't know why when I use @query in retrofit, I don't get data from server
this is my code

```
public class ServiceGenerator {
public static final String API_BASE_URL = "#########";

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

}

```
public interface IPageEndPoint {

@GET(PageParameter.GET_PAGE_BY_USER_ID_URI)
Call<PageDto> checkPageExist(@Query(PageParameter.USER_ID_4_GET_PAGE_BY_ID) String userId);
....


private void CheckPageExist(String loginId) {

    IPageEndPoint pageEndPoint = ServiceGenerator.createService(IPageEndPoint.class);
    retrofit2.Call<PageDto> call = pageEndPoint.checkPageExist(loginId);
    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<PageDto>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<PageDto> call, retrofit2.Response<PageDto> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                PageDto pageDto = response.body();
                if (pageDto == null) {
                    publicMethods.putDateInShared(Constant.PageParameter.PAGE_ID, SharedParameter.NULL_SHARED_DATA);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CreateProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Constant.CreateFragmentType.TYPE_KEY, Constant.CreateFragmentType.CREATE_PROFILE);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    String pageId = pageDto.getId();
                    publicMethods.putDateInShared(Constant.PageParameter.PAGE_ID, pageId);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainLayoutWithDrawableActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }

            } else {
                updateUi("response is not successful for check page exist");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<PageDto> call, Throwable t) {
            updateUi("response failed");
        }
    });

}
```

I've check my code many many times but I've confused about this problme.

Comment: What do you get instead? do you come in the onFailure or onResponse method?

Comment: It comes into OnResponse method but with empty response

Comment: Make sure that you have set the internet permissions in you Manifest.
If yes:
Can you add the adb logs? what does retrofit2 write to the adb logs?

Comment: The problem is though there is no error in the log, I've check the url that in the response object though and it works when I check.

Comment: You can add a HTTPLoggingInterceptor with loglevel Body to your OkHttpClientBuilder with addInterceptor. Then it should be a bit chattier

Comment: as you can see in the link below when I debug the app all of the code is works fine but the data inner response body is null
http://uploads.im/NTtny.png

Comment: buddy can u send me and example of httpLogginginterceptor?

Comment: {"PageTitle":"ndjbvtxhnshyxusjmxhyz","Description":"vxjjsb","CreateDate":"2016-06-10T00:00:00","PageType":0,"UserId":"9f390643-d4a6-4712-8cfa-65c6534f13cf","PageId":null,"ImageId":null,"URL":"nzjizks","IsMasterPage":null,"IsPublic":null,"Menulist":null,"newPostCount":0,"Id":"2aa8e9df-2806-4b20-9192-e80c5e2cbde7"}

this is the log above that show the result is returned, but why the response.body() didn't gave me this response as an object?

Comment: @jsina You can print info using httplogginginterceptor according to [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) to see what happend